# How to get items from an array and display them in a textbox;

Tags: c#

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Users/ME/Desktop/items/", ".txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

How would I display the returned results in a textbox that I have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (string file in files) {
  textbox1.Text += file + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
textbox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, files);
```

This internally uses a StringBuilder or equivalent for optimum performance and heap fragmentation prevention

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(10000);

foreach (string sFile in files) {
  sbText.AppendLine(sFile);
}

TextBox1.Text = sbText.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided this is a multi-line textbox:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    YourTextBox.Text += file + '\r\n';
}
```